# DynamoDB on demand capacity on scale to zero

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have an DynamoDB that is barely used, as in most of the day there is no access to it.
Sometimes, there is a short peak of up to 20 requests going into the DynamoDB within a second, afterwards the application wont need the DynamoDB for quite a while again.

I thought: on demand capacity is perfect for this use case. So I configured it.

But I am seeing some extreme response times during those short peaks, in the most extreme case I see response times for up to 3 minutes.

Could it be that on demand provisioning can not deal with these extremely small but sudden peaks?

Or something else I might me missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely missing something. On-demand can scale to twice it's previous peak instantly. The base peak is 2000 WCU.

I doubt your 20 requests are exceeding 4000 WCU per second. Moreover, DynamoDB would not take 3 minutes to do anything unless your scanning a table.

You don't mention where you make requests from, but you should investigate your startup latency etc.. and perhaps implement tracing using something like X-Ray to understand your bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer definitely says, that ondemand should not be the problem and that is what I asked for. I am running this in a lambda function with python and boto3 and xray definity says, that the boto3 dynamodb call is the problem. But that is something for another question.